# How to grab user track info through spotify api

Tags: spotify

I recently just got through the beginning tutorial for creating a web app with the spotify api. https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/tutorial/. The tutorial was great for showing how to authenticate a user with oauth and log in a user.

The problem I am having is with the endpoint. I can't seem to figure out how to change the endpoint so that instead of displaying a users profile, I can see a list of a users track, better yet starred or top 10 tracks.

for a 10,000 view perspective of what I want to build is a app that would allow users to easily log in through their spotify account, take their stared or top tracks and push them to a radio that I am building with an raspberry pi.

I am new to working with the spotify api and working with api's in general so whatever advice would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no way to get the "starred"-playlist. (At least it's not documented)
I don't know what you mean with "Top 10 User tracks", since this doesn't exist as far as I know

To get a list of the account's current playlists, change the URL to:
`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists`

With this URL, you will get a list of [simple-playlist-objects](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/object-model/#playlist-object-simplified) wrapped inside a [paging-object](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/object-model/#paging-object). Now you can select one of the playlists (or loop through them) and fetch its track [this way](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlists-tracks/)

**NOTE:**
If you also want to fetch private playlists, make sure you use the scope [playlist_read_private](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/)